# padding doesn't work in absolute div parent bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I add `div` with `absolute` position inside of another `div` with `relative` position using bootstrap4 like this:

```css
.p-r{
  padding:8px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  height:100px;
}
.p-a{
  bottom:3px;
  background-color:#000
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="p-r position-relative">
        <div class="p-a position-absolute w-100">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="p-r position-relative">
        <div class="p-a position-absolute w-100">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but in action, `padding` doesn't work truly in `absolute` `div`:

[image]

Comment: It’s due to the `w-100` class. The _implicit_ left position of your absolute inner div is at 8px from the left of the outer div, and when you make the inner one 100% wide now, it of course overlaps on the other side. Remove the `w-100` class, and either set `left: 8px; right: 8px;`, or use `width: calc(100% - 16px)`

Comment: @CBroe: u right, thanks. can you add your answer to I choose it?

Comment: There’s already an answer that mentions the `calc` method, feel free to accept that, if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you set `w-100` which means `width: 100% !important` of the child `div`.

To fix this, set the child div width to `width: calc(100% - 16px);`

```css
.p-r {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 100px;
}

.p-a {
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="p-r position-relative">
        <div class="p-a position-absolute">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="p-r position-relative">
        <div class="p-a position-absolute">
          text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your **absolute** div in an extra div, giving it a relative **positioning** class, specifying a `height: 100%`. I indicated class `.additional` to him:

```
<div class="p-r position-relative">
   <div class="additional position-relative">
     <div class="p-a position-absolute w-100">
        text
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```css
.additional {
  height: 100%;
}  

.p-r {
  padding:8px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  height:100px;
}
.p-a {
  bottom:3px;
  background-color:#000
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="p-r position-relative">
       <div class="additional position-relative">
        <div class="p-a position-absolute w-100">
          text
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```